# Docker and Angular prod `file does not exist` Error on stage build COPY command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i do not understand why docker cannot get my angular build folder in container.
Can you see that to help me?

[image]

If i build with docker compose command i have this error.
Below are all the steps to build my image and launch my container until the error.

```
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Building linking-front
Sending build context to Docker daemon  425.6MB
Step 1/9 : FROM node:16.19.0 AS build
 ---> b22f8aab05da
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5e2431455b65
Step 3/9 : COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 11d677269b0e
Step 4/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b5544be9159b
Step 5/9 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3403bfda57ca
Step 6/9 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ae8e7960ac33
Step 7/9 : FROM nginx:1.23.3-alpine
 ---> 2bc7edbc3cf2
Step 8/9 : COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> beca38c7be94
Step 9/9 : COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/linkingEducationSecurity-front /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat usr/src/app/dist/linkingEducationSecurity-front: file does not exist
ERROR: Service 'linking-front' failed to build : Build failed
```

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:16.19.0 AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.23.3-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/linkingEducationSecurity-front /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I use also docker-compose

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  linking-front:
    build: ./linkingEducationSecurity-front/
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./linkingEducationSecurity-front/src/
        target: /app/src
```

Comment: Where specifically is your `docker build` failing? What is the exact error message? What does your local directory structure look like?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Can you [edit] the question to include the error in plain text?  It looks like the error might be something like `file does not exist`; have you looked at the result of the first-stage build to see if the output of the build is where you expect it to be?

Comment: Isn't your path `/usr/src/app/linkingEducationSecurity-front/dist` I see `dist` and `linkingEducation..` missplaced maybe?

Comment: No i don't looked at the result of the first-stage. How can test this ?

Comment: @ExDet i think that ```/usr/src/app/linkingEducationSecurity-front/dist``` is my workdir path container.

Comment: If i use ```RUN ls``` after last command of my first-stage i get i see folder dist.

```Step 7/10 : RUN ls
 ---> Running in ad825808490b
Dockerfile
README.md
angular.json
dist
nginx.conf
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
src
tsconfig.app.json
tsconfig.json
tsconfig.spec.json```

Comment: can you show the build command in package.json also use ```RUN cd dist && ls``` to see if dist actually contains your build data

Comment: in package.json i use ```"build": "ng build"``` and i get this ```Step 7/10 : RUN cd dist && ls
 ---> Running in e8f002e82f3a
linking-education-security-front```

Comment: in fact, in my first-stage i have my dist folder but i think my second stage nginx don't see last build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since in the comments you tried to do `RUN cd dist && ls` which gave you this output :

```
Step 7/10 : RUN cd dist && ls  ---> Running in e8f002e82f3a linking-education-security-front
```

The steps and dockerfile are perfect. the `COPY` command from build folder is missing its spell

update this line :

```
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/linkingEducationSecurity-front /usr/share/nginx/html
```

to this :

```
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/linking-education-security-front /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and try rebuilding , this might work.